# Creating multiple ingress class only at specific overlays in Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a kubernetes deploy structure that looks like -

```
/base
 | - ingress.yml
 | - kustomize.yml             
 | - /dev
       |             
       | - ingress.yml
       | - kustomize.yml
 | - /staging
       |             
       | - ingress.yml
       | - kustomize.yml
 | - /prod
       |             
       | - ingress.yml
       | - kustomize.yml
```

in my base>ingress.yml, I have

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myService
spec:
  ingressClassName: default
```

I want to add another ingressClass but only in my dev and staging yamls so that they look something like -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: 
  namespace: 
spec:
  rules:
    - host: 
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: 
                port:
                  number: 
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: I2
  namespace: 
spec:
  rules:
    - host:
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: 
                port: 
                  number:
```

What I found was that I cannot do this until I modify my base ingress yml. But since that affects what the final manifest for prod looks like as well, is there a way around to adding the additional ingressClass only to certain specific overlays?

I have tried removing ingress.yml from the patchesStrategicMerge list in kustomization.yml but that doesnt work either.

Comment: What patch content and type did you try? This should work natively.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. You've said you want to add another IngressClass, but your example output only shows Ingress resources.